Cubic polynomial and roots with different signs
Given the cubic polynomial
$x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$
with real coefficients and roots.
Which conditions do I have to impose on the coefficients to guarantee that the roots will not have the same sign ?
Can I use the Hurwitz matrix ?

Descartes Rule of Signs may be useful

What does it mean for three real numbers not to have the same sign?

If the polynomial has real roots then for the roots to not have the same sign, one must be negative, one must be zero and one must be positive.

@vallev Thanks for the suggestion.

@SammyBlack, For my case I need to know that the roots of the cubic polynomial need to have different sign because those roots are coefficients of some squared terms I have and I need to avoid the trivial solution of the squared terms to be all zero.

@Lucenaposition Are there any conditions for the coefficients of the cubic polynomial to satisfy that I'm going to have different signs on the roots?

Let the cubic polynomial
$$x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$$
have the roots $r_1,r_2,r_3$. This can be split into three cases.
Case 1: $r_1=0,r_2\gt0,r_3\lt0$.
$r_1$ indicates that $c=0$. Since we know that there is only root equal to zero, we can divide the polynomial by $x$, giving
$$x^2+ax+b=0$$
The quadratic formula gives the roots $\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}$, meaning $b<0$.
Case 2: $r_1\gt0,r_2\gt0,r_3\lt0$.
Descartes’ rule of signs means that $(a,b,c)$ must be $(+,-,+)$ ($+$ and $-$ indicating positive and negative, respectively) or one of $a,b,c=0$ and the other two are $= (-,+)$. The number of negative real roots is the sign change in $$-x^3+ax^2-bx+c$$
If $(a,b,c) = (+,-,+)$, there are no sign changes, so that cannot be the signs of the coefficients. In order for there to be one sign change, $a\lt0,b=0,c\gt0$ or $a=0,b\lt0,c\gt0$. Any solution with a root equal to zero can be dealt with in much the same way as case 1.
Case 3: $r_1\lt0,r_2\lt0,r_3\gt0$.
It can be dealt with as case 2.

Thanks for your response! If one root is zero then yes I do understand the process but in general why one root needs to be zero? if you consider the $x^3 - 2x^2 -x +2$ then the roots are -1, 1, 2. and this what I'm looking for when one or two roots can have the same sign, but not the three at the same time.

@user1339278 that wasn't clear from your question. Beans wasn't the only one to think this was the most reasonable interpretation of what you said.

@user1339278 one may also consider the transformation x-> x+z where z is a negative root https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hchs2ddrbi to bring it to zero

Interpreting your question as asking for a test for when all three roots have the same sign:
Let the roots be $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. First, consider testing for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma>0$. By Vietta's formulae:
$$c=\alpha\beta\gamma$$
$$b=\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma$$
$$a=\alpha+\beta+\gamma$$
So clearly it is necessary that $a,b,c>0$. It turns out this is also sufficient.
$c>0$ means either all three roots are positive, or (wlog) $\alpha>0$ and $\beta,\gamma<0$. We have $\beta+\gamma=a-\alpha$ so
$$\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma=\alpha(a-\alpha)$$
$$< -(\alpha-a)^2$$
when $a > 0$ as $a<\alpha$.
$\beta,\gamma>-(\alpha-a)$ so $\beta\gamma<(\alpha-a)^2$ meaning $b=\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma <(\alpha-a)^2-(\alpha-a)^2=0$. Hence having $a,b,c>0$ is sufficient for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma>0$.
We can do the $\alpha,\beta,\gamma<0$ case using the same test, with the substitution $x \mapsto -x$. All coeffcients have to be positive after the map, so before the map only the odd coefficients must have been negative. Except we are rescaling so the coefficient on $x^3$ is $1$, so precisely the even coefficients would be negative.
Taken together, this means the test for either case is that $b>0$ and $sign(a)=sign(c)$. Of course, if you don't know your polynomial has real roots the test will be more complicated.

Thanks for your help and sorry for not being clear from the beginning.

The necessary and sufficient condition that a cubic equation has three real roots is
$$-27c^2 + 18 abc - 4 b^3 - 4 a^3 c + a^2 b^2 \ge 0\tag{1}$$
Now, we determine the condition that the equation has three roots with different sign given the fact that $(1)$ must be satisfied.
Case 1: $c = 0$: The equation has at least one zero root. Let us denote the two other roots by $x_1,x_2$. We have
$$\cases{x_1+x_2 = -a\\x_1x_2 = b}$$
Then, the necessary and sufficient condition that $(x_1,x_2)$ have different roots (and so, are not zeros) are:
$$b<0\tag{2}$$
Case 2: $c \ne 0$: the cubic equation will have three nonzero roots:
We notice that, the necessary and sufficient conditions that the
cubic equation have three strictly positive
roots are:
$$\cases{a<0\\b>0\\c<0} \tag{3}$$
By analogy, the necessary and sufficient conditions that the cubic equation have three strictly negative roots are:
$$\cases{a>0\\b>0\\c>0} \tag{4}$$
We deduce then, if $c \ne 0$, the necessary and sufficient condition that the cubic has three  different sign, given the fact that $c \ne 0$ are:
$$b<0 \hspace{1cm} \text{or} \hspace{1cm} \cases{a<0\\b>0\\c>0}\hspace{1cm} \text{or}\hspace{1cm}  \cases{a>0\\b>0\\c<0}\tag{5}$$
Conclusion: from $(1),(2),(5)$, the necessary and sufficient conditions that a cubic equation has 3 real roots with different signs are:
$$\color{red}{(1) \hspace{1cm} \text{and } \hspace{1cm} \left(b<0 \hspace{1cm} \text{or} \hspace{1cm} \cases{a<0\\b>0\\c>0}\hspace{1cm} \text{or}\hspace{1cm}  \cases{a>0\\b>0\\c<0}\right)} $$

Thank you for your answer!
